# Cordova Build for Android Failed - VSTS

Tags: android, cordova, android-build, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a Cordova Build for android in Visual studio team services.Most of the details are provided in the respective tabs:"android","advanced"(screenshots:[image: screenshot-1][image: screenshot-2]).Is there anything else to be filled? 
Got an error while building(screenshots:[image: screenshot-3][image: screenshot-4]).Can anyone suggest where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the wrong path chosen for the cordova working directory.Changed the working directory from "src/mobileApp/******/www" to "src/mobileAp/******". This fixed all issues.